# Python, Flask: Get request.args.get from DIV

Tags: python, flask

Is it possible to get the value inside `<div>` aside from `<input>` in Flask through `request.args.get`?. For example, `<div id="time">` then in the backend `request.args.get('time')`. My purpose for this is that I don't want to expose the `time` parameter and its value inside the url after the user hit the submit button.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<html>
  <body>
    <form>
      <div style="display:none;" id="time"></div>
      <input type="submit">
    </form>

    <script>
      document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = new Date();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best approach is instead of `div` use `hidden input` field.

Javascript:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<html>
  <body>
    <form method="POST">
      <input type="hidden" name="time" id="time">
      <input type="submit">
    </form>

    <script>
      document.getElementById("time").value= new Date();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then in python you can get the time value by request.

python:

```
request.form['time']
```